# Re-initialize etcd-cluster completely (on coreos)

Tags: linux, servers

Over the past updates (espcially the update to `etcd-wrapper`: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/tree/master/app-admin/etcd-wrapper) my etcd-cluster with five machines broke. Now I'm trying to recover from that.

Currently I only use it for the `etcd-lock` while updating the machines. So there is basically no important information in there (yet).

I tried a lot of stuff and since, in my opinion, the documentation is not that structured, I mixed a lot of infos form different parts together. Currently I'm in a state, where one node wants to elect a leader with another node. But that other node *thinks* it is part of another cluster. And I cannot do anything on the first one anymore. `etcdctl` just revokes all actions with the info, that the cluster is not healthy...

So I want to do a fresh start again!

Could someone point me to some part of the documentation, that explains that? It seems, that the *disaster recovery* part (https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/op-guide/recovery.html), that allegedly contained the info, has changed (and is also depreacted).

Additionally it would be really helpful, if someone could point me to the part of the docu, that explains how to setup a `etcd-cluster` without re-installing the whole system.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I would have gladly selected some better tags (like `coreos`, `etcd`, `etcd-cluster`), but I am not allowed to create them now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. First I disabled and deleted all `etcd2`-related units. Then I created a new dropin to the `etcd-member.service` with the following content:

```
[Service]
Environment="ETCD_OPTS=--name cluster00 \
  --discovery https://discovery.etcd.io/<MY_ID> \
  --listen-client-urls http://<NODE_IP>:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --listen-peer-urls http://<NODE_IP>:2380 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://<NODE_IP>:2379 \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://<NODE_IP>:2380"
```

I generated a new discovery id for the cluster.

Then I teared down the old cluster completely, by deleting all content of `/var/lib/etcd/*` and the directory `/var/lib/etcd2` completely and (re-)started the etcd-member service.

Be aware, that I don't have ssl enabled at this point!